# ¿Existe una forma de hacer un backup de una base de datos, pero sin las tablas?

Tags: postgresql

Mi idea es hacer un backup de una base de datos con muchas funciones propias, tipos y schema propio, para poder guardarlo en formato sql y usarlo como extensión para instalarlo en otro ordenador.

Como quiera que ya tengo tablas, pero no me interesa exportarlas, me gustaría saber si hay alguna opción (he probado varias opciones de `pg_dump` pero no doy con la tecla) para hacer lo que quiero.

Gracias

Comment: `--schema-only` ?

Comment: No, es lo primero que probé :-) Necesito exportar tipos y funciones completas, no sólo las firmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que he dado con la solución más aceptable.

1.- Hacer un volcado de la base de datos :

```
pg_dump -Fc -v -f temp.dump mibasededatos
```

2.- Listar el contenido a un fichero filtrando por palabra clave. En mi caso me es suficiente con las funciones y los tipos propios (FUNCTION y TYPE)

```
pg_restore  -l temp.dump | grep FUNCTION |grep TYPE  >listado
```

3.- Con el fichero anteriormente creado usamos la opción -L para restaurar solo los elementos listados en el archivo anterior `listado`

```
pg_restore -L listado temp.dump >mivolcadodefinitivo.sql
```

Visto [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758003/how-to-take-backup-of-functions-only-in-postgres) y [aquí](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1130311200.23228.75.camel%40Andrea.peacock.de)

Answer (score 1):

Tu regunta está respondida en otra parte del foro: [How can I export the schema of a database in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486241/how-can-i-export-the-schema-of-a-database-in-postgresql)

En **Linux** usa este comando:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -s postgres > exportFile.dmp
```

Si estás usando **Windows** puedes usar este otro:

```
pg_dump.exe -U postgres -s postgres > exportFile.dmp
```

Por cualquier otro caso deberías pasarte por la documentación de [PostreSQL - pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: Al final encontré una solución aceptable. Creo que pg_dump sin más no hace lo que busco directamente.